# What is the colloquial Cantonese translation for "还真是"?

Tags: translation, cantonese

A says: 他自从遇到车祸以后就不开车了。
B says: **还真是**，我以为他不喜欢开车呢。

Answer (score 3):

'还真是' here is similar to  "It is actually true" in English (agree/affirm to A's statement)

In Cantonese, we would say "噉又係喎"

噉(this) | 又(also) | 係(true) | 喎(final particle: indicate 'agree/affirm')

Mandarin:

> A: 他自从遇到车祸以后就不开车了。
>
> B: 还真是，我以为他不喜欢开车呢。

Cantonese:

> A: 佢自从遇到车祸之后就冇再楂車嘞。
>
> B: 噉又係喎，我仲以为佢唔鐘意楂車㖭。

Answer (score 0):

maybe "真係吖", very roughly means "really?"

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=真](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%9C%9F)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=係](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BF%82)

Comment: "真係吖"= "真是的" https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/what-is-the-meaning-of-%E7%9C%9F%E6%98%AF%E7%9A%84

Answer (score 0):

We say this when we don't think about something true in our daily life and suddenly, somebody around us mentioned it and we are like:" yeah! it is actually true! I never thought about it before!"
Literally means: "It is actually true".

Answer (score 0):

还真是 = 原來係噉

原來 >>> the unexpected original/real (reason)
係噉 >>> is this (reason told by A)

> A: 佢自從遇到車禍之後就唔再揸車。
> B: 原來係噉，我以為佢唔鐘意揸車。

Comment: 原來係噉 = 原來是這樣 or 原來如此 (so this is the real reason)

Answer (score 0):

还真是 = 噉至真

噉 >>> this (reason told by A)
至真 >>> is the unexpected real (reason)

> A: 佢自從遇到車禍之後就唔再揸車。
> B: 噉至真，我以為佢唔鐘意揸車。

Comment: Cantonese don't usually say 噉至真; "這才是真的原因" in Cantonese is "原來係噉"